# Cannot open spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I'm using python2.7 and spyder3.3.6. Spyder3.3.6 was installed by conda.
When I try to open spyder, I got:

````
File "/home/bowen/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtpy/compat.py", line 15, in <module>
from .py3compat import Callable, is_text_string, to_text_string, TEXT_TYPES
ImportError: cannot import name Callable```

What should I do to solve this?
````

Comment: *"I'm using python2.7*" You are at least two years late with updating.

Comment: @KlausD. It's depended on some packages.

Comment: That was the excuse most people had until they got into troubles like yours. Running Python 2.7 in 2022 requires a lot of extra work and knowledge. Much more then updating.

Comment: I think this related to the version of qtpy. try to install qtpy>=1.5.0 solved this.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. @bowen instally qtpy>=1.5.0 doesn't solve the problem